# How do I continue download if preventDefault is used?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery modal UI basically blocks users from downloading a file. I use `preventDefault` to stop the download manager show up. But this kills the `GET`.

After the user clicks `Agree`, how can I request proceed download?

I've googled this and most of them are doing form submission.

Comment: `window.location = 'UrlToFile'`?

Comment: A code sample would help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember the URL of file and then set it to `window.location` when user will click `Agree`.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="http://google.com" id="btn">Button</a>
        <div id="dlg">Continue?</div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var dlg$ = $('#dlg').dialog({
    title: 'Confirm action',
    autoOpen: false,
    buttons: {
        'Agree': function() {
            dlg$.dialog('close');
            window.location = dlg$.data('url');
        }
    }
}),
btn$ = $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dlg$.data('url', this.href).dialog('open');
});​
```

Comment: or as simple as `window.location = $(this).target.href` where `this` is the `<a>` tag if he's confused.